# Pigeonhole Problem with Subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Let $S$ be an arbitrary subset of $\{1, 2, ..., 99\}$ with $|S|=10$. Prove that there are two different subsets $A$ and $B$ (don't have to be disjoint) of $S$ so that
$$\text{the sum of all the elements in $A$} = \text{the sum of all the elements in $B$}$$

Ex. $S=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$, the sets $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $B = \{1,9\}$ satisfy the condition since $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10 = 1 + 9$.

Edit: I know that the total subsets would be $2^{10} = 1024$. I originally thought that the largest sum value is $945$, but that wouldn't make sense because that implies that both A and B are the same set, which they can't be, so I don't know what number to compare it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However we choose our set the largest the sum of all of the numbers in the set can be is 945.

There are $2^{10} = 1024$ subsets of our set.

There are $1024$ pigeons and $945$ pigeon-holes.  One pigeon-hole must contain more than one pigeon.

Comment: Why 945? I'm assuming you got that number from adding the last ten digits (90-99). However, that implies that A and B are the same set (because they would both have to contain those values for them to sum up to it), but it says they have to be different.

Comment: We are just trying to establish an upper bound.  It doesn't matter if this upper bound is greater than we actually need, as long as it is small enough to apply the pigeon-hole principle.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be a subset of $\{1, \ldots, 100\}$ of size $10$. There are $1023$ non-empty subsets of $S$. Thus there are two distinct subsets $A$ and $B$ of $S$ whose sum of elements leave the same remainder when divided by $1000$. Since neither of these numbers exceed $1000$, we see that these two numbers must be equal and we are done.